# Cannot import static resources in spring 5.0.6 via addResourceHandler and thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following folder structure: `'resources' > 'static' > 'styles'`;
Inside the 'styles' folder there is the file `style.css`

There is also this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ResourcesConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/styles/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/styles/", "classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

And in `index.html`, in the `head` section there is:

```
  <link th:href="@{/styles/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

I have no other configuration (like in application.properties) regarding static resources.

When I visit `index.html` in the browser I get:
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/styles/style.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addResourceLocations(String...locations)` would take in different locations as a var-arg list. But it does work like prefix or suffix to the adjacent entries.

So you should slightly change your configuration as below to get it working.

```
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/styles/**") 
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/styles/");
```